# ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

I've been given the python script where matplotlib is used , when running the script it opens the window and display graph.
its working perfectly on my laptop. But this error occurs when I upload the file on AWS elasticbeanstalk.
I successfully reproduce this error in my laptop by using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

the error raised from

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1001, in viewlim_to_dt
.format(vmin))
```

here is the code in that file

```
def viewlim_to_dt(self):
    """
    Converts the view interval to datetime objects.
    """
    print(self.axis)
    vmin, vmax = self.axis.get_view_interval()
    if vmin > vmax:
        vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    if vmin < 1:
        raise ValueError('view limit minimum {} is less than 1 and '
                         'is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This '
                         'often happens if you pass a non-datetime '
                         'value to an axis that has datetime units'
                         .format(vmin))
    return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
```

print(self.axis) shows this and then raises error

```
XAxis(100.000000,373.620690)
```

when I remove the line matplotlib.use('agg') , print(self.axis) shows

> XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(200.000000,110.000000)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(59.111111,106.555556)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(225.000000,88.000000)
>   XAxis(122.930556,106.555556)
>   XAxis(122.930556,106.555556)
>   XAxis(122.930556,106.555556)
>   XAxis(122.930556,106.555556)

Can anyone helps me out, I don't know what's going on.
I'm using python3
here is my full import

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator
```

here is the full error trace

```
File "/Users/abc/project/pythonfile.py", line 301, in plot_now
    facecolor='tab:purple', interpolate=True, alpha = 0.3, label='my_label')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1785, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5021, in fill_between
    self._process_unit_info(xdata=x, ydata=y1, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2111, in _process_unit_info
    kwargs = _process_single_axis(xdata, self.xaxis, 'xunits', kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2094, in _process_single_axis
    axis.update_units(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1478, in update_units
    self._update_axisinfo()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1496, in _update_axisinfo
    self.set_major_locator(info.majloc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1617, in set_major_locator
    self.stale = True
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 236, in stale
    self.stale_callback(self, val)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in _stale_axes_callback
    self.axes.stale = val
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 236, in stale
    self.stale_callback(self, val)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 57, in _stale_figure_callback
    self.figure.stale = val
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 236, in stale
    self.stale_callback(self, val)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 568, in _auto_draw_if_interactive
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1899, in draw_idle
    self.draw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1652, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2604, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1185, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1023, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = list(self.iter_ticks())  # iter_ticks calls the locator
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 967, in iter_ticks
    majorLocs = self.major.locator()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1230, in __call__
    self.refresh()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1250, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1001, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Comment: You **must read** the trace-backs to the end, the last line being: _"ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units"_.  Try to analyze what happens near line 300 in your script.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue by myself, by comment-out this line in my code

```
plt.ion()
```

as I said in my question, the app was running in development env (in my laptop) but not running on the AWS server.
I hope, it may help someone.