# Dual Axis plot returning ValueError: view limit is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I looked at other questions, and did not find them to assist in solving my issue. For reference, I looked at these threads:

- [Datetime issue with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607183/datetime-issue-with-matplotlib)
- [ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116963/valueerror-view-limit-minimum-0-0-is-less-than-1-and-is-an-invalid-matplotlib-d)

My issue is that despite the index of my Pandas DataFrame being a datetime dtype, I still receive the following error:

> ```
> ValueError: view limit minimum -36879.020000000004 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
> ```

From this code:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,5)) 
color = 'tab:blue'
ax1.set_title('7 Day Avg New Cases', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_xlabel('month', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Avg New Cases', fontsize=16, color=color)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x='date', y='new_pos', data = df_st, palette='OrRd')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax1.grid(False)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel('% Positive', fontsize=16, color=color)
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='date', y='pct_pos', data = df_st, sort=False, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color)
ax2.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

However, if I run the above in two pieces, it works no problem:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,5)) 
color = 'tab:blue'
ax1.set_title('7 Day Avg New Cases', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_xlabel('month', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Avg New Cases', fontsize=16, color=color)
ax2 = sns.barplot(x='date', y='new_pos', data = df_st, palette='OrRd')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax1.grid(False)
```

Which returns (barplot from above code):

[image: barplot from above code]

And then run this code:

```py
color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel('% Positive', fontsize=16, color=color)
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='date', y='pct_pos', data = df_st, sort=False, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color)
ax2.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Which returns (lineplot from above code):

[image: lineplot from above code]

The data of the dataframe:

```
        new_pos pct_pos  date
4141    120.0     0.03 2020-06-17
4142    462.0     0.03 2020-06-16
4143    259.0     0.03 2020-06-15
4144      0.0     0.03 2020-06-14
4145      0.0     0.03 2020-06-13
4146    140.0     0.03 2020-06-12
4147    177.0     0.03 2020-06-11
4148     72.0     0.03 2020-06-10
4149     66.0     0.03 2020-06-09
4150    114.0     0.03 2020-06-08
4151    146.0     0.03 2020-06-07
4152     92.0     0.03 2020-06-06
4153     96.0     0.03 2020-06-05
4154     75.0     0.03 2020-06-04
4155     64.0     0.03 2020-06-03
4156     33.0     0.03 2020-06-02
4157     59.0     0.03 2020-06-01
4158     58.0     0.03 2020-05-31
4159     54.0     0.03 2020-05-30
4160     45.0     0.03 2020-05-29
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have a look through your use of `ax2`. You've created `ax1` and put a plot on it, then called this `ax2`. You then try to modify `ax2` as though its a newly created object. To do a plot on an already created axis use the `ax=` option in seaborn. e.g. `sns.barplot(x='date', y='new_pos', data = df_st, palette='OrRd',ax=ax1)`

Comment: KWx, thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, even adjusting my code to include the ```ax=``` option, the initial error involving the dates, still occurs. Any thoughts on how to adjust that?